# How to correctly use two objects for rasterization

Tags: vector, inkscape, path

I have two objects (pink A and white B) in Inkscape, see the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot 1]

When drawing is rasterized there are artifacts in the form of pink pixels from underlying object A:

[image: Screenshot]

I have tried clipping object B to match shape of object A as shown below, but that didn't help.

[image: Screenshot 1]

What is the proper way to have two objects and produce clean image without seeing underlying object?

Comment: Before applying the difference or clipping, make sure that the lower side of the first path is lower than the lower side of the second path.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini, thanks, I did that,  see that on the first screenshot object B (white) overlaps object A (pink).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use path - difference to remove the white object B from Object A. (Ensure that the baseline of object B is not within object A but extends the baseline of object A). Once the object B is subtracted, now when you rasterize, you get a clean image without any underlying object.

[image]

This is the final image you get when you use the above method.